# How to get calculation result right in IF-THEN-ELSE?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this VBA script to do some complex calculation but the output is always 0. I have described the actual answers in the code. Why is it not working?

The Output for code

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim city_name As String, deal_type As String, cft As Integer, discount_percentage As Integer, city_check As Integer, cft_check As Integer, deal_check As Integer, discount_check As Integer, weekday_bookingfee As Double, weekend_bookingfee As Double
    discount_percentage = Range("b4").Value
    city_name = Range("b5").Text
    deal_type = Range("b6").Text
    cft = Range("b7").Value
    If city_name = "Delhi" Then
    city_check = 1
    ElseIf city_name = "Mumbai" Then
    city_check = 1
    ElseIf city_name = "Bangalore" Then
    city_check = 1
    ElseIf city_name = "Chennai" Then
    city_check = 3
    ElseIf city_name = "Kolkata" Then
    city_check = 3
    ElseIf city_name = "Hyderabad" Then
    city_check = 2
    ElseIf city_name = "Pune" Then
    city_check = 3
    ElseIf city_name = "Ahmedabad" Then
    city_check = 4
    ElseIf city_name = "Chandigarh" Then
    city_check = 4
    ElseIf city_name = "Jaipur" Then
    city_check = 4
    ElseIf city_name = "Goa" Then
    city_check = 4
    Else:
    End If
    If deal_type = "Food" Then
    deal_check = 2
    ElseIf deal_type = "Total" Then
    deal_check = 1
    ElseIf deal_type = "Buffet" Then
    deal_check = 1
    ElseIf deal_type = "Alcohol" Then
    deal_check = 3
    ElseIf deal_type = "Coupon" Then
    deal_check = 4
    ElseIf deal_type = "Explosive" Then
    deal_check = 4
    Else:
    End If
    If cft >= 5000 Then
    cft_check = 1
    ElseIf cft < 5000 And cft >= 2500 Then
    cft_check = 2
    ElseIf cft < 2500 And cft >= 1500 Then
    cft_check = 3
    ElseIf cft < 1500 And cft >= 800 Then
    cft_check = 4
    ElseIf cft < 800 And cft >= 500 Then
    cft_check = 5
    ElseIf cft < 500 Then
    cft_check = 6
    Else:
    End If
    If (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 3) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 80 And weekday_bookingfee = 60
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 70 And weekday_bookingfee = 60
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 50 And weekday_bookingfee = 40
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 50 And weekday_bookingfee = 40
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 35 And weekday_bookingfee = 30
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 30 And weekday_bookingfee = 25
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 25 And weekday_bookingfee = 20
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 20 And weekday_bookingfee = 15
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 20 And weekday_bookingfee = 15
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 15 And weekday_bookingfee = 10
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 15 And weekday_bookingfee = 10
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 5 And weekday_bookingfee = 5
    Else:
    End If
    If (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 3) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (80 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (70 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (35 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (30 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (30 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (25 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (25 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.75)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (5 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (5 * 0.75)
    Else:
    End If
    If (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 3) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (80 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (70 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (35 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (30 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (30 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (25 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (25 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.5)
    ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check) = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (5 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (5 * 0.5)
    Else:
    End If
    Range("b10").Value = weekday_bookingfee
    Range("b11").Value = weekend_bookingfee
 End Sub
```

I need actual weekday_bookingfee and weekend_bookingfee as I've described them in the code

Comment: `Else:` isn't doing what you think it is. Also because you don't have an else condition just get rid of it. But seriously, instead of multi elseif just use a case statement. For the last 3 massive if statements, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The codeline

```
weekend_bookingfee = 35 And weekday_bookingfee = 30
```

Is not evaluating two different statements, since that “AND” is concatenating a boolean expression instead

Change all your:

```
Then
weekend_bookingfee = ... And weekday_bookingfee = ...
```

To:

```
Then
weekend_bookingfee = .... : weekday_bookingfee = ...
```

Where the “:” is actually separating two different statements

Answer (score 1):

By using a few arrays you can completely do away with all that `If ElseIf` nastiness at the end and get it down to just 2 lines of code. We know the address of the elements of the array so we use simple maths in the bottom two lines of code to determine which element we should be using.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Dim city_name As String, deal_type As String, cft As Long, discount_percentage As Long, city_check As Long, cft_check As Long, deal_check As Long, discount_check As Long, weekday_bookingfee As Double, weekend_bookingfee As Double, Disc_arr As Variant, Weekend_arr As Variant, Weekday_arr As Variant
Dim resultCalc
Disc_arr = Array(, , 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
Weekend_arr = Array(, , , 80, 70, 50, 50, 35, 30, 25, 20, 20, 15, 15, 5)
Weekday_arr = Array(, , , 60, 60, 40, 40, 30, 25, 20, 15, 15, 10, 10, 5)
discount_percentage = Range("b4").Value
city_name = Range("b5").Text
deal_type = Range("b6").Text
cft = Range("b7").Value

Select Case city_name
    Case "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Bangalore"
        city_check = 1
    Case "Hyderabad"
        city_check = 2
    Case "Chennai", "Kolkata", "Pune"
        city_check = 3
    Case "Ahmedabad", "Chandigarh", "Jaipur", "Goa"
        city_check = 4
End Select

Select Case deal_type
    Case "Total", "Buffet"
        deal_check = 1
    Case "Food"
        deal_check = 2
    Case "Alcohol"
        deal_check = 3
    Case "Coupon", "Explosive"
        deal_check = 4
End Select

If cft >= 5000 Then
    cft_check = 1
ElseIf cft < 5000 And cft >= 2500 Then
    cft_check = 2
ElseIf cft < 2500 And cft >= 1500 Then
    cft_check = 3
ElseIf cft < 1500 And cft >= 800 Then
    cft_check = 4
ElseIf cft < 800 And cft >= 500 Then
    cft_check = 5
ElseIf cft < 500 Then
    cft_check = 6
End If

resultCalc = WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check)

weekend_bookingfee = CDbl(Weekend_arr(resultCalc)) * CDbl(Disc_arr(discount_percentage / 10))
weekday_bookingfee = CDbl(Weekday_arr(resultCalc)) * CDbl(Disc_arr(discount_percentage / 10))

End Sub
```

Also change all your Integer declarations to Long, we don't use Integer in VBA.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim city_name As String, deal_type As String, cft As Integer, discount_percentage As Integer, city_check As Integer, cft_check As Integer, deal_check As Integer, discount_check As Integer, weekday_bookingfee As Double, weekend_bookingfee As Double
Dim resultCalc
discount_percentage = Range("b4").Value
city_name = Range("b5").Text
deal_type = Range("b6").Text
cft = Range("b7").Value




Select Case city_name
    Case "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Bangalore"
        city_check = 1
    Case "Hyderabad"
        city_check = 2
    Case "Chennai", "Kolkata", "Pune"
        city_check = 3
    Case "Ahmedabad", "Chandigarh", "Jaipur", "Goa"
        city_check = 4
End Select

Select Case deal_type
    Case "Total", "Buffet"
        deal_check = 1
    Case "Food"
        deal_check = 2
    Case "Alcohol"
        deal_check = 3
    Case "Coupon", "Explosive"
        deal_check = 4
End Select


If cft >= 5000 Then
    cft_check = 1
ElseIf cft < 5000 And cft >= 2500 Then
    cft_check = 2
ElseIf cft < 2500 And cft >= 1500 Then
    cft_check = 3
ElseIf cft < 1500 And cft >= 800 Then
    cft_check = 4
ElseIf cft < 800 And cft >= 500 Then
    cft_check = 5
ElseIf cft < 500 Then
    cft_check = 6
End If


resultCalc = WorksheetFunction.Sum(city_check, deal_check, cft_check)

If (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 3) Then
weekend_book ingfee = 80 And weekday_bookingfee = 60
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 70 And weekday_bookingfee = 60
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 50 And weekday_bookingfee = 40
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 50 And weekday_bookingfee = 40
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 35 And weekday_bookingfee = 30
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 30 And weekday_bookingfee = 25
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 25 And weekday_bookingfee = 20
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 20 And weekday_bookingfee = 15
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 20 And weekday_bookingfee = 15
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 15 And weekday_bookingfee = 10
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 15 And weekday_bookingfee = 10
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 50) And (resultCalc = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = 5 And weekday_bookingfee = 5
End If

If (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 3) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (80 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (70 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (35 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (30 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (30 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (25 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (25 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.75)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 40) And (resultCalc = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (5 * 0.75) And weekday_bookingfee = (5 * 0.75)
End If

If (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 3) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (80 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 4) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (70 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (60 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 5) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 6) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (50 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (40 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 7) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (35 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (30 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 8) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (30 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (25 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 9) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (25 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 10) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 11) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (20 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 12) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 13) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (15 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (10 * 0.5)
ElseIf (discount_percentage = 30 Or discount_percentage = 20) And (resultCalc = 14) Then
    weekend_bookingfee = (5 * 0.5) And weekday_bookingfee = (5 * 0.5)
End If


End
```

Comment: I have downvoted because I'm not sure what you intended to do here. The `If ... ElseIf` statements were not causing the problem OP described, likewise the `If ... And ... Then` lines were, even though ugly, not the problem either. The only thing causing OP's results were not handled by you. OP is evaluating boolean expressions when they intended to assign the correct values to `weekend_bookingfee` and `weekday_bookingfee`.

Comment: I won't downvote you because you are a new contributor but please in future post some comments to explain what your solution is, just a block of code which doesn't answer the question really doesn't help anyone.